# How I do make an OAuth request using NSURLSession?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlsession

I have a client ID and secret that I am supposed to send in a post request in order to receive a token to access an API (OAuth). I am using:

```
NSURLSessionConfiguration *sessionConfiguration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
```

to setup my authorization headers; however, I keep returning:

```
{
    error = unauthorized;
    "error_description" = "Full authentication is required to access this resource";
}
```

I have double and triple checked my client ID and secret, but I keep getting this response.

Here is the code that I am using to make my request:

```
    NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://"];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: @"/oauth/token?" relativeToURL:baseURL];
    NSURL *absoluteURL = [url absoluteURL];

    NSURLSessionConfiguration *sessionConfiguration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
    sessionConfiguration.HTTPAdditionalHeaders = @{@"Authorization" : [CLIENT_SECRET_PREFIX stringByAppendingString:[self base64Encode:CLIENT_SECRET_TOKEN]]};
    sessionConfiguration.HTTPAdditionalHeaders = @{@"Content-Type" : @"application/json"};

    NSURLSession *session =[NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:sessionConfiguration];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:absoluteURL];
    [[session dataTaskWithRequest:request
               completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
                   NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
                   NSLog(@"%@", json);
    }] resume];
```

Can anyone please help me to solve this problem ? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: have you tried adding the header to request?

Comment: OAuth is tricky. I've used this library with success: https://github.com/nxtbgthng/OAuth2Client